# Laravel artisan command - Change option in script?

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

Is it possible to change options passed to a Laravel command in the PHP file? I've tried a couple things like `$this->option('optionName', 'newValue');` but have not found a solution. Also, I can't simply get the value and set it to a new variable because I'm extending the migration command and need to reset the option for that. The `--path` option to be exact.

Comment: If you're extending it, why not override the `$signature` property?

Comment: Creating a multi-tenant app. Iterating through schemas available and need to change the path dynamically based on the current schema used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for anwsering my own question but I found a solution that will work in my case:

`$this->getDefinition()->getOption("optionName")->setDefault("newValue");`

Since its only overriding the default, it only works if the option was not passed through the CLI. if someone has a better way of handling this please provide the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The options are fetched from the `input` interface. This interface also provides a `setOption` method that can be used. Thus, you can change an option as follows:

```
$this->input->setOption('optionName', 'yourValue');
$this->option('optionName'); // Returns 'yourValue'
```